# making a query with é as column name in php drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, pdo, drupal-7

I got this table with a column name `Catégorie` which I can't rename (long story) and that é is bothering me big time.

I can't seem to query that column.

I got the following code

```
$query_brands = "SELECT distinct catégorie as merk FROM GSProduct";

    $resultBrands = $phpbb->query($query_brands);
    $brandArr = array();
    foreach($resultBrands as $brand){
        $brandArr[$brand->merk] = $brand->merk;
    }
```

In mysql the query works fine, but in php I get an exception:

> PDOException: in meisjesschoenen_filter_form() (line 198 of /home/mediaspe/domains/mediaspex.be/public_html/juniorsteps/sites/all/modules/meisjesschoenen/meisjesschoenen.module)

I tried putting it between `' '` but then I just get 1 empty result instead of the 7 results I should get

Help is appreciated a lot!!

UPDATE:

I found the following lines of code in settings.php and I added the collation ad followed:

```
array (
    'juniorsteps_gem' =>
    array (
      'database' => '*****',
      'username' => '*****',
      'password' => '*****?',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    ),
```

Also I found in mysql that the collation of my database/table also is utf8_general_ci so that should be ok.

UPDATE2 (could not self answer yet)

The problem was my file.
I've used notepad++ to convert my file from ANSI to UTF 8 and now it works.

Thx all for the push in the right direction!!

Comment: What is the encoding of the database connection (PDO), and in which encoding are you saving the file you're written that SQL statement in?

Comment: I used a drupal Class to connect to the database, I'm trying to find out the encoding in the documentation no luck yet.
this line makes the connection: $phpbb = Database::getConnection($target='juniorsteps_gem',$key='juniorsteps_gem');

How can I find the encoding type of the file? It's just a .php file on which I edit with notepad++

Comment: I tried using:
$phpbb = Database::getConnection($target='juniorsteps_gem',$key='juniorsteps_gem');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $phpbb);

but it didn't work.

Comment: Good to see you found the culprit. I've added the file-encoding as an answer, feel free to accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the file you're writing the SQL statement is correctly encoded, e.g. UTF-8. That's a setting in the editor you're using.

Otherwise you are sending the wrong characters to the database, because you get a PDO Exception an invalid one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ` quote instead of '.

Try to use:

```
"SELECT distinct `catégorie` as merk FROM GSProduct";
```

Comment: it still gives that same PDOException. :s

Comment: @Stephan-Celis Do you send 'SET NAMES UTF8;' after create connection?

Comment: I tried using the following lines then
"$phpbb->query('SET NAMES UTF8');
$resultBrands = $phpbb->query($query_brands);"
but it did not work